# Gap Below Footer in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, footer

I have a Wordpress site. I'm using the Blank Slate plugin on top an installed Nirvana theme by Cryout Creations. I'm using it to create my homepage from scratch and will eventually switch to a blank theme altogether.

My issue is that have a 32px gap between my footer and the bottom of the page (I measured it). I have trawled online for the last week and tried every single solution I have seen to remove it (wrapping, negative margins, 100% body height etc. etc.), yet absolutely nothing has been able to remove this gap, and place my footer at the bottom of the page.

Rather than paste my code, I thought I'd ask if anyone is aware of Wordpress itself causing such an issue, or perhaps whether a  plugin is capable of doing so? If so, is there a way I can identify the cause?

Link to site: https://nelsontrails.co.nz/8937-2/

Thanks in advance for any help, it would greatly appreciated!

Comment: you article tag has margin-bottom:36px css.. plz remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have margin bottom on `article.page`. Please copy the below code and paste it to **Customizer** -> **Additional Css** to get rid of that space.

```
article.post, article.page {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, that worked perfectly! Thank you so much.

Comment: Great..Please select my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you got `margin-bottom: 36px;` in your `article.post, article.page` class in your css please remove it and the white space will be gone